# if i have zoom api key and secret and i want to hide those keys

Tags: javascript

I want to add the API key and secret on another page and call it here
and call it again in those variables?

```
**const ZOOM_API_KEY = XXXX_XXXXX_XXXXX_XXXX (here)
const ZOOM_API_SECRET = XXXX_XXXXX_XXXXX_XXXX (here)
const SHEET_INPUT = 'input';
function generateReport() { const zoomMeeting = new ZoomMeetingHandler(ZOOM_API_KEY, ZOOM_API_SECRET, getValidMeetingID()).getMeeting();
displayResult(zoomMeeting);
}**
```

Comment: Where is this code being run?

Comment: google apps script